# editing an excel sheet using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am trying to edit an excel sheet using apache poi,
I have a worksheet having 2 rows and 5 columns
if second cell of row 2 is null then it should add a 3rd row ,
but i am getting a class not found exception, although the UpdateXLS is present in my D drive.

Here is the code:

```
public class New {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
     InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("D:\\UpdateXLS.xls");
        //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue("a test");

        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UpdateXLS.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Please include stacktrace.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\UpdateXLS.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.New.main(New.java:17)

Answer (score 1):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465200/editing-an-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi?noredirect=1#comment41568387_26465200) , I can suggest you that check file exits on the path specified.

Use [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
File f = new File("D:\\UpdateXLS.xls");
//check whether file exists or not to avoid any further exceptions
if(f.exists()){
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
  ......
  .......
  ........
}
```

---

> [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)
>
> Signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed.
>
> This exception will be thrown by the FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile constructors **when a file with the specified pathname does not exist**.
>
> It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is **inaccessible**, for example when an **attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing**.

---

When you are writing a file check your path

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UpdateXLS.xls");
```

Change to

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\UpdateXLS.xls");
```

Comment: changed itstill the same problem

Comment: @ITI : are you sure file exists on path `D:\UpdateXLS.xls`? and if exists then check that is it read only by right click on file --> properties. If read only then remove that read only

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UpdateXLS.xls");
```

try to replace the line with:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\UpdateXLS.xls");
```

Comment: i replaced it
still the same problem